# Upgrade from EF4 to EF5 stopping referenced object from being set

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two tables, Company and Employee, with a one to many reference from Company to Employee.  Each table has a navigation property to the other.  In EF4 when I set Employee.company it would also add the Employee object to the Employee collection in the Company object.  Since updating from EF4 to EF5 this is no longer the case and it instead remains null.  How can I get this behavior back?  I have included the EF4 and EF5 versions of the referenced objects below:

Employee EF4:

```
Public Property Company() As Company
    Get
        Return CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference(Of Company)("Model.FK_Employee_Company", "Company").Value
    End Get
    Set
        CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedReference(Of Company)("Model.FK_Employee_Company", "Company").Value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Employee EF5:

```
Public Overridable Property Company As Company
        Get
            Return _Company
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Company)
            _Company = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Company"))
        End Set
End Property
```

Company EF4:

```
 Public Property Employees() As EntityCollection(Of Employee)
    Get
        Return CType(Me,IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection(Of Employee)("Model.FK_Employee_Company", "Employee")
    End Get
    Set
        If (Not value Is Nothing)
            CType(Me, IEntityWithRelationships).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection(Of Employee)("Model.FK_Employee_Company", "Employee", value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Company EF5:

```
Public Overridable Property Employees As ObservableCollection (Of Employee)
        Get
            Return _Employees
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection (Of Employee))
            _Employees = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Employees"))
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: The new code is using Events.  Are the events properly registered?

Comment: Yeah the property changed event fires fine and is working as expected

Comment: Are the tables getting filled?  I seen similar issues with DGV.  The DGV does not get repainted automatically so nothing is seen even though the datasource contains data.  So with a DGV you have to set to null : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt